# Can't remove an element from a list using UpdateItem

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to remove a `LIST` element from an `ITEM` in my DynamoDB table. I believe I have the correct setup, but can't seem to pass an integer.

```
var params = {
  TableName: DB_TABLE_NAME,
  Key:{
    "Key": KEY_VALUE
  },
  UpdateExpression: "REMOVE List[:n]",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":n": 1
  },
  ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};
```

I then run the UpdateItem function, which I use for other use cases.

```
db.update(params, (err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The following error is returned

```
"message": "Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \":n\", near: \"[:n]\"",
```

When I remove `ExpressionAttributeValues` and replace `:n` with the value 1 (which references an existing List element), it successfully executes.

I'm obviously missing something here, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how do you find out which integer to delete ? im stuck here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although (at least for node.js) the SDK doesn't accept AttributeValues, this can be resolved by adding the variable into the UpdateExpression string.

```
UpdateExpression: "REMOVE List[" + listNumber + "]",
```

Comment: Just ran into this. It's 2020 and this is still the case for boto3 DynamoDB update_item() :(